# Most size efficient place to put photos in ios app

Tags: ios

I am working on an app right now and it has ~25 photos that are needed. I currently have all the photos in as assets but it made the app 150 MB larger. Is there any way I can reduce this amount of storage needed. Could I put the photos in another place or maybe download them from the web?

Comment: You can use on demand resources https://www.raywenderlich.com/520-on-demand-resources-in-ios-tutorial but the user will still need to download the same amount of data eventually and you will need to include placeholder data for use while the resources download. Perhaps you could use lower resolution images as placeholders.

Comment: Try to use other format for photos: jpg or png with compression. I think what 6 MB per image is too many.